# Simple Closed Form of a Function

Tags: calculus

Find a simple closed form for $F(n)=(1^2+1)1!+(2^2+1)2!+\cdots+(n^2+1)n!$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

How can I manipulate the powers so that they can be converted into factorials?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Gamma Function?

Comment: Given a problem like this, the thing to do is work out cases $F(1), F(2), F(3)$ and so on, looking for a pattern.

Comment: @DanZimm: Yes, using the Gamma Function is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2+1)k!=\sum_{k=1}^n \{(k+1)(k+1)!-2kk!\}=-\sum_{k=1}^n k k!+(n+1)(n+1)!-1=\ -\sum_{k=1}^n ((k+1)!-k!)+(n+1)(n+1)!-1=n(n+1)!$

Comment: Comparing this to the first few calculations yields that it is consistently 1 too many. Could my solution be $F(n)=n(n+1)!$?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake, corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint
Note
$$n^2+1=(n+1)(n+2)-3(n+1)+2$$
so
\begin{align*}
(n^2+1)n!
&=(n+2)!-3(n+1)!+2n!\\
&=[(n+2)!-(n+1)!]-2[(n+1)!-n!]
\end{align*}